# dropzone upload only one file

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js for my drag-drop file upload solution. I want to upload only one file,if i upload second file the first one should be remove and second one should be uploaded.
any idea how to do it..

here is my html

```
<form class="dropzone dz-clickable" action="upload.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload element"></i>
  <div style="color:gray;">Drag and drop or click to upload image</div>
  <input type="hidden" name="filenameEmail" class="filenameEmail" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="side" value="front">
</form>
```

i changed dropzone.js

```
maxFiles: 1
```

it allow to upload only one file but i cant remove the previously uploaded file.please help me out.thanks in advance

Answer (score 103):

**maxFiles: 1** is used to tell dropzone that there should be only one file. When there is more than 1 file the function **[maxfilesexceeded](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-maxfilesexceeded)** will be called, with the exceeding file as the first parameter.

here is a simple function to delete preview of first file and add the new one :)

```
maxFiles:1,
init: function() {
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            this.addFile(file);
      });
}
```

Comment: When I drag and drop, after the first one, the image preview of the files goes away and it's a gray preview.

Comment: It is not perfect because it fires the `error` event. Bad when tracking errors. @darkbaby123 works for latest version.

Comment: downvoted because @darkbaby123 answer works in a more generic cases (dragging files or selecting them)

Answer (score 32):

I used event `maxfilesexceeded` with method `addFile` and rans into **infinite loop** of event call. It should be the problem of using `addFile` because I didn't see it mentioned in both official site or GitHub wiki. Finally I solved with `addedfile` event. The Dropzone.js is the latest version when I write (4.3.0).

```
init: function() {
  this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
    if (this.files.length > 1) {
      this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! the answer @NeoNe is also good but when you drag a file it still uploading two files. I tried yours, it goes both ways :)

Comment: This one worked for me. @NeoNe fires the error event. Bad when tracking errors.

Comment: where do you put this code?

Answer (score 19):

Limiting `maxFiles` to 1 still allow selecting multiple files in upload dialog. To disallow selecting multiple images in configuration specify following init function:

```
maxFiles:1,
init: function() {
    this.hiddenFileInput.removeAttribute('multiple');
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work for me. I have only one input, do I need to add another (hidden) input?

Comment: @AndrewFox Did you figured it out? It doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik unfortunately not, I am still having this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.init = function () {

                 this.hiddenFileInput.removeAttribute('multiple');
                 this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
                     this.removeAllFiles();
                     this.addFile(file);
                 });
             };
```

this is wokrk for me.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of two solutions does the job for me in the init function:

```
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            if (this.files.length > 1) {
                this.removeAllFiles()
                this.addFile(file);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
const dropzoneInput = document.querySelectorAll('.dz-hidden-input')
for (const input of dropzoneInput) {
    if (input.getAttribute('multiple')) {
        input.removeAttribute('multiple')
    }
}
```

This what it does is validate if the dropzone input have attribute of multiple, if it have, remove id

Note: the class **.dz-hidden-input** can be different for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions here accept two files but it's a bit random which file gets uploaded. Better way is to notify the user.

```js
init: function () {
    this.on('addedfile', function () {
        if (this.files.length > 1) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            alert('Drop only one file');
        }
    });
}
```

**Note:** `maxFiles` is not needed as we don't use the `maxfilesexceeded` here. Just set the `this.files.length > 1` accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

None of these solutions worked for me.

The `maxfilesexceeded` event is called too late i.e. after an attempt to add the file.

Other solutions using `this.removeFile(this.files[0]);` resulted in a `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null".` or an infinite loop.

**Solved by** -

```
maxFiles: 2,
init: function () {

    this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        if (this.files.length > 1) {
            this.files = this.files.slice(1, 2);                        
        }
    });

}
```

Works when using `dz-clickable` (file chooser btn) and drag and drop.

Comment: Be careful as `maxFiles: 2` allows multiple selections. It is a bad user experience and misleading on mobiles. See @darkbaby123 answer