# Dropzone - max files not working

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have tried setting up the limit of uploading files to only one. I have tried all the suggestions from the previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005054/dropzone-upload-only-one-file) but nothing worked for me. Each time I was able to upload multiple files and as many as like.

This was one of my attempts:

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
     url: "/admin/upload",
     params: {
        _token: token
      }
 });
 Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 1,
    init: function() {
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function() {
        if (this.files[1]!=null){
          this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
        }
      });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {

    }
  };
```

And this is how I call the scripts:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/dropzone/dropzone.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/image-upload.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the dropzone configuration into two different methods. And only the first one is being used the one that contains the `url` option, the second, that contains the `maxFiles` option is ignored.

You have to either include all the configuration inside the first method that creates dropzone programmatically like this:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
    url: "/admin/upload",
    params: {
       _token: token
    },
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 1,
    init: function() {
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function() {
        if (this.files[1]!=null){
          this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
        }
      });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {

    }
 });
```

Or with second method that uses the dropzone autodiscover feature, if your dropzone element has the id `#dropzoneFileUpload` do it like this:

```
 Dropzone.options.dropzoneFileUpload = {
    url: "/admin/upload",
    params: {
       _token: token
    },
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 1,
    init: function() {
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function() {
        if (this.files[1]!=null){
          this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
        }
      });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {

    }
};
```

Comment: That's really strange method to remove file, try this:

`//...
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function (file) {
        this.removeAllFiles();
        this.addFile(file);
    });`

Comment: @VladimirPak, yeah you're right, it's a strange way, but it's what the OP had, I just kept it there, the question was about the `maxFiles` option being ignored, and that I am positive it was because of the split configuration.